# Triggers INSTEAD OF Update, Como filtrar por data

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Olá, Antes de tudo obrigado pelo tempo de todos vocês da comunidade.

Vamos lá!

Vou jogar as informações e depois tentar, da melhor forma possível explicar o problema.

Tenho 3 Tabelas:

Pessoa

Lista

Escala

```sql
CREATE TABLE PESSOA 
(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    NOME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    MESA INT,
    DATACRIACAO DATETIME NOT NULL,d
    DATAMOD DATETIME,
    SETOR_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ACESSO_ID INT

    CONSTRAINT PK_PESSOA_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_SETOR_PESSOA_ID FOREIGN KEY (SETOR_ID)
        REFERENCES SETOR(ID)
)   

CREATE TABLE ESCALA 
(   
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    STS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    TIPO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(11),
    DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL VARCHAR(11),
    HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(8),
    HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL VARCHAR(8),
    PESSOA_ID_CREATE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PESSOA_ID_UPDATE INTEGER,
    DATACRIACAO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    DATAMOD DATETIME 

    CONSTRAINT PK_ESCALA_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PESSOA_ESCALA_ID_CREATE FOREIGN KEY (PESSOA_ID_CREATE)    
        REFERENCES PESSOA(ID)  
) 

CREATE TABLE LISTA 
(   
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
    PESSOA_ID INT NOT NULL,
    ESCALA_ID INT NOT NULL,
    DATACRIACAO DATETIME NOT NULL,
    INDICE INTEGER NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT PK_LISTA_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PESSOA_LISTA FOREIGN KEY (PESSOA_ID)
        REFERENCES PESSOA(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_ESCALA_LISTA FOREIGN KEY (ESCALA_ID)
        REFERENCES ESCALA(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

A minha lógica dessas tabelas são:
Várias pessoas podem estar em uma escala, onde adiciono as pessoas a lista e apenas coloco a escala_id que elas pertencem.

Se alguém souber como melhorar isso agradeço(não sei se é a melhor forma)

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

> Quero uma trigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE que:
>
> Impeça o UPDATE(é claro)
>
> Verifique se existe alguma escala atuando naquela data
>
> Se existir alguma, não dar update e avisar(escala tal está atuando nessa data)

Segue Querry SQL do código que criei para Insert(caso aja inserção e exista outra escala na mesma data) e a trigger para update, mas está com um probleme(deixando atualizar mesmo tento escala atuando naquela data)

**Desconsiderar o campo (sts = ativo ou inativo) da escala**

```sql
/* Insert */  
CREATE TRIGGER  IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT ON ESCALA 

INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 
DECLARE 

@NOME                 VARCHAR(150),
@STS                  VARCHAR(20),
@TIPO                 VARCHAR(20),
@DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(11),
@DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(11),
@HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(8),
@HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(8),
@PESSOA_ID_CREATE     INTEGER,
@PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     INTEGER,
@DATACRIACAO          DATETIME,
@DATAMOD              DATETIME

        SELECT 

        @NOME                 = NOME                 , 
        @STS                  = STS                  ,
        @TIPO                 = TIPO                 , 
        @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
        @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
        @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
        @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
        @PESSOA_ID_CREATE     = PESSOA_ID_CREATE     ,
        @PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     = PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     , 
        @DATACRIACAO          = DATACRIACAO          ,
        @DATAMOD              = DATAMOD              

        FROM INSERTED  

        IF((SELECT 'FAIL'

                WHERE EXISTS(SELECT  @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(DATE, @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL  ) BETWEEN DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL AND TIPO = @TIPO) 
                )                                         
                   AND EXISTS(SELECT @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(DATE, @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL  ) BETWEEN DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO) 
                )                                         
                   OR EXISTS(SELECT @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(TIME, @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO)
                )                                         
                   AND EXISTS(SELECT @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(TIME, @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL  ) BETWEEN HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO) 

                ))  != '')

                        INSERT INTO ESCALA 
                                (
                                NOME                 , 
                                STS                  ,
                                TIPO                 , 
                                DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                PESSOA_ID_CREATE     ,
                                PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     , 
                                DATACRIACAO          ,
                                DATAMOD              
                                ) VALUES 
                                (
                                @NOME                 , 
                                @STS                  ,
                                @TIPO                 , 
                                @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                @PESSOA_ID_CREATE     ,
                                @PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     , 
                                @DATACRIACAO          ,
                                @DATAMOD                 
                                )

        ELSE RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL INSERIR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

/* update*/  
CREATE TRIGGER  IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_UPDATE ON ESCALA 

INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
DECLARE 
@ID                   INTEGER,
@NOME                 VARCHAR(150),
@STS                  VARCHAR(20),
@TIPO                 VARCHAR(20),
@DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(11),
@DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(11),
@HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(8),
@HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(8),
@PESSOA_ID_CREATE     INTEGER,
@PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     INTEGER,
@DATACRIACAO          DATETIME,
@DATAMOD              DATETIME,

@UPDATE_NOME                  VARCHAR(150),
@UPDATE_STS               VARCHAR(20),
@UPDATE_TIPO                  VARCHAR(20),
@UPDATE_DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(11),
@UPDATE_DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(11),
@UPDATE_HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL VARCHAR(8),
@UPDATE_HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   VARCHAR(8),
@UPDATE_PESSOA_ID_CREATE     INTEGER,
@UPDATE_PESSOA_ID_UPDATE      INTEGER,
@UPDATE_DATACRIACAO       DATETIME,
@UPDATE_DATAMOD           DATETIME

        SELECT 
        @ID                   = ID                   ,
        @NOME                 = NOME                 , 
        @STS                  = STS                  ,
        @TIPO                 = TIPO                 , 
        @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
        @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
        @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
        @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
        @PESSOA_ID_CREATE     = PESSOA_ID_CREATE     ,
        @PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     = PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     , 
        @DATACRIACAO          = DATACRIACAO          ,
        @DATAMOD              = DATAMOD              

        FROM inserted   

        IF((SELECT 'FAIL'

                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(DATE, @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ) BETWEEN DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL AND TIPO = @TIPO AND ID != @ID) 

                   AND EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(DATE, @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL ) BETWEEN DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO  AND ID != @ID) 

                   OR EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(TIME, @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL) BETWEEN HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO   AND ID != @ID)

                   AND EXISTS (SELECT  * FROM ESCALA WHERE CONVERT(TIME, @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL ) BETWEEN HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL AND HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL  AND TIPO = @TIPO  AND ID != @ID) 

            )   != 'FAIL')
        BEGIN



                        UPDATE ESCALA SET

                                NOME                 = @NOME                 , 
                                STS                  = @STS                  ,
                                TIPO                 = @TIPO                 , 
                                DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = @DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = @DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = @HORA_ATUACAO_INICIAL ,
                                HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = @HORA_ATUACAO_FINAL   ,
                                PESSOA_ID_CREATE     = @PESSOA_ID_CREATE     ,
                                PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     = @PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     , 
                                DATACRIACAO          = @DATACRIACAO          ,
                                DATAMOD              = @DATAMOD     

                        WHERE ID = @ID


        END
        ELSE RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ATUALIZAR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRIGGER INSTEAD OF INSERT

```
CREATE TRIGGER IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT ON ESCALA
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    --Termina se não há registos para processar
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
       RETURN;

    IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
         FROM INSERTED A
        INNER JOIN ESCALA B
           ON A.TIPO = B.TIPO -- Mesmo tipo
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL <= B.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL  -- Interseção entre as datas
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL >= B.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL  -- Interseção entre as datas
    ) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL, PESSOA_ID_CREATE, DATACRIACAO)
        SELECT NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL, PESSOA_ID_CREATE, DATACRIACAO FROM INSERTED
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL INSERIR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

    END        
END
```

TRIGGER INSTEAD OF UPDATE

```
CREATE TRIGGER IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_UPDATE ON dbo.ESCALA 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    --Termina se não há registos para processar
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
       RETURN;

    IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
         FROM INSERTED A
        INNER JOIN dbo.ESCALA  B
           ON A.TIPO = B.TIPO -- Mesmo tipo
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL <= B.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL >= B.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL  
          AND A.ID <> B.ID
    ) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE E 
           SET E.NOME                 = I.NOME
             , E.STS                  = I.STS
             , E.TIPO                 = I.TIPO
             , E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL
             , E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL   = I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL
             , E.PESSOA_ID_UPDATE     = I.PESSOA_ID_UPDATE
             , E.DATAMOD              = GETDATE()



          FROM INSERTED I
         INNER JOIN ESCALA E
            ON E.ID = I.ID
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ATUALIZAR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);
    END
END
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema com o seu trigger está na forma como compara as datas das escalas e resulta talvez da forma como a informação está guardada na tabela. Note também uma diferença entre os triggers `INSTEAD OF INSERT` e `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` na forma como compara o resultado das várias cláusulas EXISTS:

```
IF (SELECT 'FAIL' WHERE EXISTS ...)   != '')
vs
IF (SELECT 'FAIL' WHERE EXISTS ...)   != 'FAIL')
```

Antes de mostrar uma possível solução, convém lembrar que não é garantido que o trigger irá disparar para cada registo inserido individualmente. Esse é provavelmente o erro mais comum na programação de procedimentos trigger, em T-SQL: assumir que a cada chamada do procedimento apenas um único registo existe nas tabelas virtuais. Deve ter isto em consideração sempre que cria um trigger.

Deste facto resulta um problema adicional: Se a aplicação permitir que vários registos sejam inseridos ao mesmo tempo (através de BULK INSERT ou INSERT INTO ESCALA FROM ...), não é apenas necessário comparar os novos registos (na pseudo tabela INSERTED) com a tabela ESCALA, mas também garantir que os novos registos, entre si, não violam as suas pré-condições.

Posto isto, sugiro primeiro que altere a forma como representa as datas de inicio e fim. Se ao invés de usar `VARCHAR`, usar `DATETIME` as comparações tornam-se muito mais simples. E em termos de espaço, comparando com o `VARCHAR` será mais eficiente.

Deixo aqui uma solução que acredito o irá ajudar a resolver o seu problema, mas com algumas limitações. Repare que neste pequeno exemplo fiz a alteração na definição da sua tabela `Escala`. Alterei a definição das colunas que representam o início e o final da escala. Ao invés de usar 4 colunas do tipo `VARCHAR` para representar data e hora separadamente, uso duas do tipo `DATETIME` para representar a mesma informação: DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL e DATA_ACTUACAO_FINAL.

```
CREATE TABLE ESCALA 
(   
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NOME VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    STS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    TIPO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL DATETIME2 NOT NULL
)
```

Aqui fica o trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT ON ESCALA
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    --Termina se não há registos para processar
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
       RETURN;

    IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
         FROM INSERTED A
        INNER JOIN ESCALA B
           ON A.TIPO = B.TIPO -- Mesmo tipo
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL <= B.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL  -- Interseção entre as datas
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL >= B.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL  -- Interseção entre as datas
    ) 
        INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
        SELECT NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL FROM INSERTED
    ELSE 
        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL INSERIR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

    END        
END;
```

Testando o INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
SELECT 'NOME1', '1', '1', '2019-03-21 14:00:00.000000', '2019-03-21 17:00:00.000000'
```

Resulta:

> 1 rows affected

Inserindo outro registo:

```
INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
SELECT 'NOME2', '1', '1', '2019-03-20 14:00:00.000000', '2019-03-21 15:00:00.000000'
```

Resulta:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 53]
>   NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL INSERIR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO
>   MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA

Fica aqui o trigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE

```
CREATE TRIGGER IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_UPDATE ON dbo.ESCALA 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE AS
BEGIN
    --Termina se não há registos para processar
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) 
       RETURN;

    IF NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1 
         FROM INSERTED A
        INNER JOIN dbo.ESCALA  B
           ON A.TIPO = B.TIPO -- Mesmo tipo
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL <= B.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL
          AND A.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL >= B.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL  
          AND A.ID <> B.ID
    ) 
        UPDATE E 
           SET E.NOME = I.NOME
             , E.STS = I.STS
             , E.TIPO = I.TIPO
             , E.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL = I.DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL
             , E.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL = I.DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL
          FROM INSERTED I
         INNER JOIN ESCALA E
            ON E.ID = I.ID
    ELSE 
        RAISERROR ('NÃO FOI POSSÍVEL ATUALIZAR A ESCALA, NÃO É POSSÍVEL DUAS ESCALAS DO MESMO TIPO ATUAREM NA MESMA DATA/HORA',16,1);

END
```

**Sobre as limitações:**

Estes dois triggers funcionam quando os registos forem inseridos 1 a 1. Se tentar a inserção de vários registos através de uma instrução INSERT INTO ESCALA FROM ....

```
INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
    SELECT 'NOME1', '1', '1', '2019-03-21 14:00:00.000000', '2019-03-21 17:00:00.000000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'NOME2', '1', '1', '2019-03-20 14:00:00.000000', '2019-03-21 12:00:00.000000'
```

Resultará:

> 2 rows affected

Só você sabe se esta situação é passível de acontecer ou se o acesso à base de dados está limitado por um front-end. Caso seja possível diga, que eu tento colocar aqui uma forma para tentar mitigar o problema.

Comment: Olá, não tem necessidade de inserir dois registro em uma única instrução, mas se puder acredito que será de grande ajudar mostrar como evitar isso, para evitar problemas futuros.

Agradeço a resposta, mas a trigger que você mostrou impede a inserção no mesmo dia e hora.

Exemplo: 
Se eu criar duas escala ambas do mesmo dia, mas em horários inicial e final diferente da erro
Escala 1
25-03-2019 08:00:00 até 25-03-2019 11:59:00

Escala 2 
25-03-2019 12:00:00 até 25-03-2019 18:00:00

Comment: Essa situação não pode ocorrer. Se copiar a definção da tabela Escala e o do trigger IMPEDIR_ESCALA_MESMA_DATA_TIPO_INSERT e se executar os seguintes INSERTS, não vai despoletar a mensagem de erro. INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
SELECT 'NOME1', '1', '1', '2019-03-25 08:00:00.000000', '2019-03-25 11:59:00.000000' 

INSERT INTO ESCALA(NOME, STS, TIPO, DATA_ATUACAO_INICIAL, DATA_ATUACAO_FINAL)
SELECT 'NOME2', '1', '1', '2019-03-25 12:00:00.000000', '2019-03-25 18:00:00.000000'

Acho que o unico problema é o END; final que deveria ser removido.

Comment: @GustavoPedro, fica aqui o link para o SQLFiddle para poder comprovar. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84220/1
Faça "Build schema" para definir a tabela e "Run SQL" para ver os dois registos inseridos.